# How to understand if a port is open from remote

Tags: networking, router, openvpn

Situation:

- in a remote site I have a Raspberry hidden behind an ADSL router.
- the provider gave me a public IP, so that I don't need a DDNS
- on the Raspberry I installed OpenVpn server on port 1194 UDP
- on the router I opened the port `1194 UDP`
- the system worked properly for a few months.
- Then the provider changed my public IP and since then I'm no more able to connect to the remote system

What I did

- I went to the remote site and on the Raspberry I reinstalled OpenVpnServer in order to get a new certificate (with the new public IP) to be used on the client.
- I made a test while being there, using a client connected via cell phone access point, but no answer.
- Since then I'm no more able to connect to the remote side.
- I can ping the public IP and I get the correct answer, but nothing else.

What I'm asking

Now I'm trying to understand if the problem lies on the ADSL router that locks the traffic through the port `1194 UDP` (despite the fact that I opened the port) or if there is something wrong on the Raspberry side.
Since I'm absolutely not expert with networking, I'd like to know how could I detect who is the enemy, the ADSL router or the Raspberry configuration.
Is there any tool that I could use there to pinpoint the failing system. Something like a "ping". I understand that I've to move there, on the remote site. But what could I do there?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to run tcpdump on the Pi and see if the traffic is reaching it.  To be honest though, certs have nothing to do with IPs and its reasonable to speculate the new IP you are behind is behind asome kind of ISP block

Comment: I would advise to download [paping](https://code.google.com/archive/p/paping/downloads) . This software allows you to ping ports instead of devices. Ping locally first, if that works, ping externally. so `paping 192.168.1.1 -p 1194` and see if you get a response. Great for troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks @davidgo. So you say that when the public IP (that is supposed to be static) changes, I just have to modify the text part of the certificate where the IP is written. No need to generate a new certificate. Is it correct?

Comment: Thank you @LPChip. So you say that from my home I could "paping" the public IP address (let's say it is 2.235.219.xxx) with "paping 2.235.219.xxx -p 1194" and see what happens. But who is expected to answer? The router or the raspberry behind the router? And, more, does "paping" work only on TCP/IP or also on UDP? I'm asking this because i didn't open port 1194 on TCP/IP but only on UDP. FYI the raspberry is in the internal network on IP 192.168.1.75.

Comment: You don't need to modify the certificate at all. The certificate has no concept of an IP address. When a web client connects to the https port (typically 443) it says to the server "this is the domain name I want to retrieve data off". The server says " here is the cert associated with the domain name", the browser checks its valid based on math and the case cert it already knows. None of this requires an IP address. Anything can intercept the IP streams destination without impact- its only the cert negotiation that matters.

Comment: the 64-bit version of paping supposedly is able to ping udp ports, though I have not tried that as I don't have udp ports open to test. you would first ping the internal ip address and it will ping the port on the rasphberri pi directly. If that is succesful, you ping the router from externally. This way, you can see if the rasphberri is at fault or the router, or maybe your ISP.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your public IP has not changed? Sometimes the ISP give out leashes based on mac address of the modem/router. Since that changed, it is possible the ISP handed you a new IP address and that new address will now be an unchanged address.

Comment: @LPChip: yes, I'm sure that the Static Public IP address is not changed. While on the remote site I made a test pinging the Public IP from outside, then I disconnected the router and the ping stopped answering. When I reconnected the router the ping worked properly. Indeed the provider did change the public IP without notice, but this was many months ago, and now I'm using the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your router "has" the public IP and you are using NAT for the devices connected to the router:

1. A public IP is not enough, you'll need a static IP in order to avoid DDNS
2. "Opening" a port is not enough, you need to set up a port forward: on your router port `1194` should be forwarded to the Raspberry

Note: Currently your are just pinging the router not the Raspberry, that's why the ping works but OpenVPN doesn't. In order to be able to ping the Raspberry you need to forward ICMP traffic to the Raspberry as well.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 
Yes, I asked to the provider to set a STATIC public IP. So that the public IP doesn't change. No need for Dynamic DNS. 
On the router side (did I tell you that I'm not expert?) I went to the "port configuration page" and configured something like "Traffic UDP on ports from 1194 to 1194 will be forwarded to ports from 1194 to 1194". This is what I called "opening the port". Is it correct?
Now I'd like to sit on the raspberry console and start some tool that says "You're receiveng data on the 1194 port". How to do it?

Comment: @Salrandazzo it's called PortForward (not opening the port) and your setup is incomplete: the traffic arriving at publicIP:1194 needs to be forwarded to raspberryIP:1194